# Property [fname] not found on type [com.modelimpl.Modelmvcimpl]

Tags: java, jsp, model-view-controller, jstl

I am trying to display all data which is stored in database to admin.jsp page but due to some reason I am getting this error. **Property [fname] not found on type [com.modelimpl.Modelmvcimpl]**
My Admin.jsp code is as per below.

Admin.jsp

```
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${al}" var="user">
            <tr>
               <td>${user.fname}</td>
            </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Modelmvcimpl.java

```
package com.modelimpl;
import com.model.Mvcgetset;
public class Modelmvcimpl implements Mvcgetset 
{
        public static String fname;
        public String getFirstName() 
        {
            return fname;
        }
        public void setFirstname(String fname)
        {
            this.fname = fname;
        }
}
```

I don't know why this error is occuring. Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: Use `${user.firstName}`, EL goes over getters, not directly to the attribute.

Comment: Thank you very much it works properly now.